# giving invalid response .well-known/acme-challenge when run certbot ssl

Tags: apache, ssl, http-status-code-404, certbot

I run this command to get ssl for a web site. but its giving this error

certbot run -a webroot -i apache -w projectroot -d "domain"

- The following errors were reported by the server:

  Domain: xxxxxx.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: ip address: Invalid response from
  http://xxxxxxx.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/FARXRJrLbosFKOFHJWI7Z9r3d5a5zG75QLzDbDz0134:
  404

  To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
  entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
  contain(s) the right IP address.

any one knows how to fix this in apache server and let me know where is the location which make the .well-known folder

Comment: i did not uploaded any images when asking this question . all are in text format

Comment: Sorry - I must have picked the wrong of multiple open tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the folders and put the file in apache document root directory which is set by DocumentRoot in config file